# Prevent from installing open-vm-tools-desktop / @platform-vmware on EL 7

Tags: redhat, vmware-esx, kickstart, packages, anaconda

When installing RHEL 7/CentOS 7 as a VMware ESX guest, the installer (Anaconda) automatically detects the virtualization host, then install the appropriate tools (`open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop`, also known as the VMware Tools). [for those who have acces to Red Hat portal, I have also opened a discussion https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2770061 ].

It is certainly nice to install `open-vm-tools` automatically since it enable many features (with few dependencies).

Unfortunately, anaconda also install the package `open-vm-tools-desktop` which has a lot of dependencies (Xwindow and GTK library, etc). Not so useful, and not desirable on a small, secured, headless server.

I tried to explicitly explicitly remove `open-vm-tools-desktop` in Kickstart `%packages` section without success:

```
%packages
-open-vm-tools-desktop
```

**How to prevent RHEL 7 from installing `open-vm-tools-desktop` ?**

Answer (score 2):

Red Hat and CentOS don't provide a lot of information on how this work. I found two Solution/Workaround. This is a new feature, in since EL7.2 as far as I can tell, it's known as  *Platform-specific packages are now installed automatically based on the used virtualization platform* (BZ#884385), it's new in [anaconda-19.31.123-1.el7 /RHBA-2015:0312-4](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2015-0312.html)

## Why is it installed / How that work ?

This is a feature implemented by [Add platform specific group selection (#884385)](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/anaconda-patches@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/ZQXTCM4S2T4Y5FRRPLCG666FVY5YB2TE/)  (look for `get_platform_groupid` in [Anaconda source code](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/blob/master/pyanaconda/packaging/__init__.py#L784) ).

The way it work is that anaconda execute [systemd-detect-virt](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html) to detect the virtualisation or container host (vmware, qemu, kvm, microsoft... docker, lxc, openvz...) then adds a YUM group named `platform-$VIRTNAME`

List the (special/hidden) groups:

```
$ yum group list hidden -v "@platform*" | grep "^ "
   Platform Development (platform-devel)
   VMware platform specific packages (platform-vmware)
```

Show the group content:

```
$ yum group info platform-vmware
Group: VMware platform specific packages
 Group-Id: platform-vmware
 Description: Virtualization utilities and drivers for VMware
 Default Packages:
   open-vm-tools
   open-vm-tools-desktop
```

## Solution 1: Prevent from installing

Simply add `@platform-vmware --nodefaults` in the `%packages` section of your kickstart.

Make sure you don't put a dash at the begining of the line, as it won't prevent the group from being installed. You can still add a line `open-vm-tools` to install that package only !

Kickstart snippet example:

```
%packages
## Workaround to prevent automatic installation 
## of package open-vm-tools-desktop (an X11 library) 
## http://serverfault.com/q/815356/238995
## https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2770061
## Note: DON'T put a dash at the begining of the line !
## The way it works, is that it instructs Anaconda to install
## the "Mandatory" package from the YUM group 'platform-vmware',
## but not the "Defaults" and "Optional".
## Since this group has no Mandatory package... it actually
## install .. nothing !
@platform-vmware --nodefaults
#Optionaly, install this if needed:
#open-vm-tools
```

The way it works, is that it instructs Anaconda to install the "*Mandatory*" package(s) from the YUM group `platform-vmware`, but not the "*Defaults*" and "*Optional*" package(s). Since this group has no Mandatory package... it actually **install nothing** !

## Workaround: Purge the packages by hand,

Purge the packages *by hand*. Be carefully, as it may uninstall other packages, so double check before pressing `yes` ! (and fine tune the list if needed)

```
/usr/bin/yum erase open-vm-tools-desktop harfbuzz libthai libtiff mesa-libgbm mesa-libglapi libXxf86vm libxshmfence libdrm libpng mesa-libEGL libXau libXft mesa-libGL pixman atk cairo gdk-pixbuf2 hicolor-icon-theme libxcb libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage libXfixes libXrender pango pangommatkmm cairomm gtk2 gtkmm24 libX11 libXext libXi libXinerama libXrandr libXtst glibmm24 graphite2 libX11-common
```

## Other solutions tried, but not working:

- explicitly remove `@platform-vmware` in Kickstart `%packages` section.
- explicitly remove `open-vm-tools-desktop` in Kickstart `%packages` section

## Diagnostic / Anaconda's log

Look for a tring like this in Anaconda's `packaging.log:

```
INFO packaging: Adding platform group platform-vmware
```

Other *platforms* reported by [systemd-detect-virt](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html) aren't supported yet, and may report:

```
INFO packaging: Platform group kvm not available.
INFO packaging: Platform group microsoft not available.
INFO packaging: Platform group oracle not available.
INFO packaging: Platform group xen not available.
INFO packaging: Platform group qemu not available.
INFO packaging: Platform group zvm not available.
INFO packaging: Platform group bhyve not available.
```

Comment: To purge the packages manually, it would be better to run `yum erase open-vm-tools-desktop` and then `yum autoremove`, as opposed to listing all the dependencies explicitly.